# Entitydatasource declarative markup handle errors when save data in details view

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, entity-framework

I have a simple page with `EntityDataSource` and `DetailsView` control  that will be used to capture the user input. All drag and drop and declarative markup. No code in the code behind and It works without any error.

But if the user input duplicate key ( `EmployeeID` is the key ) , system throws an error on the page. I want to catch this error and display a simple message to user saying it is duplicate.

My qyestion is, since I am using declarative markup and all drag and drops, where do I put the exception handlling ? which event should I use and how to catch the error ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer... You can handle this in GridView or DetailsView RowUpdated event as below. Everwhere people talk about EntityDataSource updated event but that did not work for me anyway.

Working code:

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdated(object sender, GridViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Exception != null)
            {
                Response.Write(e.Exception);
                e.ExceptionHandled = true;
                Response.Write("Error handled row");
            }
        }
```